# Use of "relish" in this context?

Tags: present-continuous

Can I use **"I am relishing my work"** or **"I relish my work"**?

Which one is correct? If both are incorrect what would be correct sentence using the word *relish*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say anything you want. The problem is whether what you're saying will sound natural to native speakers or not. I wouldn't use **relish** in such a simple sentence like that. I would instead say "**I enjoy doing my job**" or **"I'm enjoying my job".**
**Relish** might be too much a formal word to be used simply like that.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd say _relish_ is "too formal," but I do agree that if I told a coworker, "I relish my work," he might smile, assuming I was either being sarcastic, or perhaps using a little bit of hyperbole for humorous effect.